# Is "Vayugad L'Melech Mitzrayim" used as a template for Torah cantillation (trop)?

Tags: beshalach, trop-cantillation

It seems that several times when I've discussed different styles of Torah cantillation (trop) with someone, and they wanted to sing a sample of it, the text they chose was "Vayugad l'melech mitzrayim ki varach ha'am ..."

Is that just me? And if this is common, how did that verse get chosen?

Comment: Not in my experience...

Comment: I think it's just you.

Answer (score 9):

That pasuk is not used in my experience as an example of trop.

However, in the book [An'im Zemorot by Elli Schorr](http://seforim.blogspot.com/2010/02/anim-zemorot-modern-purim-parody.html) he gives a list of the different Ta'amim using common examples of their occurrence. I know that when I first read this I recognized which psukim 90% of the examples were from just based on the trop from the one word. Maybe other ba'alei kriya will have the same experience. [image: Trop Examples from _An'im Zemirot_ by Eli Schorr]

Comment: This is done tongue-in-cheek. It is a list of words with well-known trop that people commonly say to "assist" the ba'al kriyah when he reaches that part of the laining. The paragraph bills itself as an aid to help these people "practice" for those special occasions.

Comment: Does that say "ta'amei hamikra l'nudnikim"? That's hilarious.