# What's wrong with being a "Ka'eyleh Jew"?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Since *Pesach* is on the horizon I've gotten started learning some of the *halachos* of *Pesach*. In the *leining* for *Pesach* (from [*Bamidbar* 28:23](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0428.htm#23)), we have a command:

> תַּעֲשׂוּ, אֶת-אֵלֶּה.‏
>
> Make an *eilleh*.

Since the verb תַּעֲשׂוּ is second-person plural, it is obviously referring to the congregation listening to the *keriat haTorah*. Naturally, in most good *shuls*, the congregation fulfills this *mitzvah* by singing the following word, כָּאֵלֶּה (*kaeilleh*), along with the *ba'al keriah*. I imagine that this is a very important *mitzvah* since we read about it all eight days of *Pesach*.

Yet I have seen that [some people](http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom/topic/are-you-a-kaeylah-jew) appear to look down on the practice of observing this *mitzvah deoraita*. Interestingly, the person in the thread linked above also appears to disapprove of the rabbinic institutions of singing along with "*simcha liartzecha visason li'eyrecha*", "*bichag hamatzos bichag hasvauous*...", and even "*tov umaitiv hedoresh lanu*" from the Yom Tov *shmoneh esrei*. <sup>*</sup>

I would have thought that the person who posted that thread was simply an [*am haaretz gamur midoraysa*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1268/am-haaretz-gamur-mideoraysa) except for the fact that even [here on Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-to-deal-with-the-parts-of-the-torah-reading-that-are-pre-empted-by-the-congr#comment200485_118) some apparently *frum* Jews look down on people who want to fulfill this important *mitzvah*. Someone even [published a book](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13676/1713) referring to people who do this as *nudniks*. How can people speak with such disdain about fulfilling what is obviously an important *mitzvah*

<sup>* Though for some reason he doesn't mention singing along with "*Avraham yage-e-el*" during Shabbos *mincha*. I thought this was part of the same rabbinic institution. Am I wrong about this?</sup>

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that these "scrupulous" Jews are actually insulting the entire congregation!

You see, substituting an "eilleh" with a "ka'eilleh" is actually a slap in the face. Let me explain.

When Hashem told Moshe about the upcoming plague of the death of the first born, he said it would be at "chatzos," exactly midnight. However, when Moshe informed Paroh, he told him that the plague would be at "ka'chatzos," roughly midnight, because Paroh and his astronomers wouldn't be able to calculate when exactly midnight was, they would miscalculate, and assume that their calculation was correct and Hashem had actually missed exactly midnight (Rashi to Shemos 11:4). Because the Egyptian astrologers were too incompetent to calculate exactly, Moshe had to change "chatzos" to "ka'chatzos."

When these individuals yell out "ka'eilleh," they are insinuating that the congregation is too dense to know an "eilleh" when they see one, and therefore they call out "like an eilleh" to make sure everyone doesn't jump to their own incorrect conclusions about whether an *eilleh* was made or not made.

Shame on them.

Comment: Very interesting! So what is the proper way to fulfill this mitzvah?

Comment: The mitzvah is fulfilled at kiddush after davening when the rabbi shouts EILEH very loudly before trailing off into a mumble for "mo'adei hashem mikroo-ai koydesh ..."

Comment: I had no recollection of this answer at all and it made me laugh out loud when I saw it just now (as did @Yitzchak 's comment)

Answer (score 5):

Let's hop across to Sukkos, courtesy of the "Tes Vav / Tes Vav" wormhole; where we find the concept of "taaseh -- veLo min ha'asui." *Make it anew, it can't be something already made.*

Okay! Hold on to the that concept, and take that wormhole/chute/ladder back over to Pesach: you'll notice on the first day of Pesach most people haven't gotten into the rhythm yet (and/or they're half-asleep from the Seder) so they're not chiming in. From that moment on, it's already *asui* -- already made, as a solo part for the *baal kriah*, ergo from there on out the guiding rule is *ta'aseh -- velo min ha'asui*, i.e. the "ta'asu" no longer applies.

Comment: I don't know. In my shul there are plenty of people who have been waiting excitedly all year to fulfill this mitzvah.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing, and the suggestion is offensive. My grandmother A"H was named Kayla.